# Spring Boot custom query order by aliased aggregate column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpql

I have a table like this called `my_objects`:

```
| code | description | open | closed |
+ ---- + ----------- + ---- + ------ +
| 1    | first       | 0    | 1      |
| 1    | first       | 1    | 0      |
| 2    | second      | 1    | 0      |
| 2    | second      | 1    | 0      |
```

I'm returning a JSON object like this:

```
{
    "totalItems": 2
    "myObjs": [
        {
            "code": 1,
            "description": "first",
            "openCount": 1,
            "closedCount": 1
        },
        {
            "code": 2,
            "description": "second",
            "openCount": 2,
            "closedCount": 0
        }
    ],
    "totalPages": 1,
    "curentPage": 0
}
```

My query in my repository (`MyObjsRepository.java`) looks like this:

```
@Query(
    value = "SELECT new myObjs(code, description, "
    + "COUNT(CASE open WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as openCount "
    + "COUNT(CASE closed WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END) as closedCount) "
    + "FROM MyObjs "
    + "GROUP BY (code, description)"
)
Page<MyObjs> findMyObjs(Pageable pageable);
```

This works, but I run into an issue when trying to sort by my aggregated columns. When I try to sort by `openCount`, the `Pageable` object will contain a `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort` with an Order with the property `openCount`. The log for my application shows what's going wrong (formatted for readability):

```
select 
    myObjs0_.code as col_0_0_, 
    myObjs0_.description as col_1_0_, 
    count(case myObjs0_.open when 1 then 1 else null end) as col_2_0_,
    count(case myObjs0_.closed when 1 then 1 else null end) as col_3_0_
from my_objects myObjs0_
group by (myObjs0_.code, myObjs0_.description)
order by myObjs0_.openCount asc limit ?
```

The aliases aren't preserved, so I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column myObjs0_.openCount does not exist
```

I've tried renaming the sorting parameters, adding columns with the aliased names to my entity, and adding open and closed to the group by clause. I think I may be able to solve this with a native query, but I'd really rather not do that. Is there a way to resolve this issue without a native query?

Edit:

The `MyObjs` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_schmea", name = "my_objects")
public class MyObjs {
    @Column(name = "code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "open")
    private Integer open;

    @Column(name = "closed")
    private Integer closed;

    /* getters, setters, and constructor */
}
```

The `MyObjsDto` looks like this:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PUBLIC_ONLY)
public class MyObjsDto {
    @JsonProperty(value = "code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty(value = "description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty(value = "openCount")
    private String open;

    @JsonProperty(value = "closedCount")
    private String closed;

    /* getters, setters, and constructor */
}
```

Comment: Please share your MyObjs class structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort uses column which is present in the table. Here you are calculating it.
I would suggest you to explore and use `@Formula` annotation to perform the same action.

```
@Formula("COUNT(CASE open WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END)")
private Integer open;

@Formula("COUNT(CASE closed WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null END)")
private Integer closed;
```

and use this attributes to apply the sorting.