# Case on Where Clause of JPQL is not Working

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

This is my code:

```
   @Query("SELECT m from BankAccount m " +
            "inner join BankBranch br on br.id = m.bankBranch.id " +
            "inner join Bank bn on bn.id = m.bank.id " +
            "WHERE m.status = true " +
            "and (lower(m.accountNo) LIKE %:search% " +
            "or lower(br.branchName) LIKE %:search% " +
            "or lower(bn.name) LIKE %:search%) " +
            "AND case "+
            " when :featureName = 'Staff Advance Register' then m.isStaffAdvanceRegister = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Staff Bill Payment' then m.isStaffBillPayment = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Final Settlement' then is_final_settlement = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Vendor Payment' then is_vendor_payment = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'BKash' then is_bkash = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Brac Security Money Deposit' then is_brac_security_money_deposit = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Fund Receive' then is_fund_receive = true "+
            " when :featureName = 'Foreign Currency Register' then is_fc_register = true "
            " END "
    )

    Page<BankAccount> getBankAccountListByFeatureName(@Param("featureName") String featureName,@Param("search") String search, Pageable pageable);
```

But this is not working, it returns error of bean creation after adding case portion of query in the where clause. Where is the problem?

Comment: post your error logs and entity class.

Comment: Yeah, as @GnanaJeyam says, please post a `stacktrace` and/or `logs` when getting the error of bean creation.

Comment: The case when returns a value, not a statement. You can’t do it that way via query. Use fe criteriabuilder.

Comment: Why not use `@Formula` for your case conditions and rest of the query will be clearer. Check  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156577/spring-boot-custom-query-order-by-aliased-aggregate-column/73158197#73158197](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73156577/spring-boot-custom-query-order-by-aliased-aggregate-column/73158197#73158197)